# Flask Cookies are not working

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am new to flask, just started to write code in flask. I tested my code on EC2 and local machine, on both cookies are not working. I dont know whats the problem.

```
@app.route('/cart/', methods = ['GET'])
def cart_addition():
         response.set_cookie('productid', '11')
         if 'productid' in flask.request.cookies:
                                output = 'Pass'
         else:
                                output = 'Fail'
         return render_template('output.html',output=output)
```

But after running the server this printing 'Fail'. I even tried on localhost.

I am running the server on this

```
 app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `make_response` function: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#cookies

```
from flask import make_response

@app.route('/cart/', methods = ['GET'])
def cart_addition():
    if 'productid' in flask.request.cookies:
        output = 'Pass'
    else:
        output = 'Fail'

    resp = make_response(render_template('output.html', output=output))
    resp.set_cookie('productid', '11')
    return resp
```

Comment: Tnx it worked, I used the make_response, but I was not returning resp.